# Get all referenced assemblies in current project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, reference

I'm trying to build method that will check all dlls that are not system dlls, and download them from FTP. For example I have some devxpress DLLs referenced and newtonsoft (Json.net). Problem is when I try to get list I only get 16 of them and there are more on reference list.

```
List<string> moduli = new List<string>();
Assembly a = typeof(frmPostavkeDokumenata).Assembly;
Assembly assem =Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();

foreach (AssemblyName an in assem.GetReferencedAssemblies())
{
    if (!an.Name.Contains("System") && 
        !an.Name.Contains("mscorlib") && !an.Name.Contains("Microsoft"))
    {
        moduli.Add(an.Name);
    }
}
```

This is my reference list:

[image]

Comment: Just because the project references them, doesn't mean they are actually needed and actually linked to your final executable.

Comment: ReSharper has an option to [find and remove unused references](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Refactorings__Remove_Unused_References.html).

Comment: I understand that, but I don't care if I download one DLL more. That way I'm sure that application won't drop any unexpected exceptions because of DLL missing.

Comment: It's dangerous just to use a _filename_ as a means to identify a .NET assembly. Uniqness is determined by _filename, version, culture and public key_

Comment: I agree but I'm trying to simplify it until I get all references, then I can check everything other. But thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

`Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies` just retrieve the referenced assemblies which are used as a Type in your Assembly. So, actually it is impossible to retrieve Visual Studio references using reflection.

**This is the only way to perform it that you should parse .csproj file of assembly/project.**

Comment: hmm, I don't know if I'm right but, shouldn't it suppose to be easy to get all references. How do other languages behave on this topic?

Comment: I couldn't understand clearly. What exactly do you mean "other languages" ?

Answer (score 1):

When you compile your project in visual studio - only dlls which are actually used by your project will be compiled into dll\exe metadata as referenced assemblies, regardless of which are listed in "references" section.

You have several options:

1. Recursively build list of referenced assemblies. This will give you a list of all assemblies used by your application and all assemblies used by its dependencies, which should be a complete list of dlls you might actually need at runtime.
2. Subscribe to `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event and provide missing dlls there (better option).